# Retrieve a connection string from appsetting.json in a simple console app (Core 3.1)

Tags: configuration, console-application, .net-core-3.1, appsettings

I'm writing a very simple console app that needs to dig into a database and read values. I'm having issues getting the connection string from the appsettings.json. After a whole load of googling I've found a bunch of solutions, each of which with their own issues such as being out of date or just returning null values with no obvious reason why. The main (and most common) method i've found to do it is as below:

```
static void Main()
{
    var configuration = GetConfiguration();
    var connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionsStrings").GetSection("DbName");
}

public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    return builder.Build();
}
```

This somewhat works but just returns a null value where I'd expect the connection string.

The appsettings.json is as below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbName": "Connection string"
  }
}
```

If anyone can spot anything obvious and help me along, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning to everyone out there. Don't be like me. Don't add your appsettings.json then for 17 hours completely forget to check the properties and make it an embedded resource while getting annoyed that your returned value is just null all the time. You would think after years of coding I'd learn my lesson....